# MongooseError: Operation `articles.insertOne()` buffering timed out after 10000ms, Node.js, Mongoose

Tags: node.js, mongoose

I've been following a tutorial on making a Markdown blog with Mongoose (https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=1NrHkjlWVhM),

Here is the part of the code that seems to be causing the area:

```
const Article = require('./../models/article')
const router = express.Router()

router.get('/new', (req, res) => {
    res.render('articles/new', {article : new Article()})
})

router.get('/:id', (req, res) => {
    res.send(req.params.id)
})

router.post('/', async (req, res) => {
    let article = new Article({
        title: req.body.title,
        markdown: req.body.markdown
    })

    try{
    article = await article.save()
    res.redirect(`/articles/${article.id}`)
    } catch (e) {
        console.log(e)
        res.render('articles/new', {article: article})
    }
})

module.exports = router
```

When I run this, I get the error:

```
MongooseError: Operation `articles.insertOne()` buffering timed out after 10000ms
    at Timeout.<anonymous> (C:\Users\USER\Documents\Folder\Folder\Website\node_modules\mongoose\lib\drivers\node-mongodb-native\collection.js:185:20)
    at listOnTimeout (internal/timers.js:549:17)
    at processTimers (internal/timers.js:492:7)
```

article.js code:

```
const mongoose = require('mongoose')

const articleSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
    title: {
        type: String,
        required: true
    },
    markdown: {
        type: String,
        required: true
    },
    createdAt: {
        type: Date,
        default: Date.now
    }
})

module.exports = mongoose.model('Article', articleSchema)
```

Comment: I think you need to show us your Article code.

Comment: I've edited the post and added that part at the bottom

Comment: Just to be sure, you have the code to connect to the database already?

Comment: Yes, I have the code to connect to the database,

mongoose.connect('mongodb://localhost/news', {
    useNewUrlParser: true, 
    useUnifiedTopology: true
})